# How to customize SlidingDrawer to lock in the middle of the Screen?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

Anybody has a sample project or any idea to make a customized Sliding Drawer which is able to lock in the middle of the screen, cover the whole screen, and of course hide at the bottom?

The second, and the third is not a big deal. But the first one, I think a bit of workaround is needed. Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using this attribute: `android:topOffset`.
This attribute means the offset from the top when the drawer was expanded.
Then the only thing worry about would be how to get the screen's height.

Comment: try to describe your answer.  :-)